# Use specific service depending on class field

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

I have a class X with field `validator`

```
class X {
  private Validator validator = Validators.A;

}
```

Now, in other component, I have a method:

```
private MyService myService;

[...]

public void foo(X x) {
  myService.validate(x);

}
```

I want to force Spring to use specific MyService implementation depending on which Validator has class X? Is there any Spring mechanism or pattern?

Hope, you understand. Thanks for any help.

So far I wrote a lot of if statements. It works, but I hope I could write it better.

Comment: Maybe `@Conditional` is what could help you: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-conditional-annotations

Comment: You would need a factory, that factory will have all kind of services injected and based  on Validator in X you can return the service. You can also call the factory as a wrapper service.